# PhysicsBody stays after translation and rotation

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, skphysicsbody, scnnode

I have a node with a cube attached which represents for example a door. The physicsbody type is .static. If i animate the node up, rotate it and animate it down to the orignial position of the physicsbody stays in the upper position. 
In the debug mode the color of the phyisicsbody is first grey (i asume grey = .static), after the translation up, the physicsbody stays at the bottom. As soon as I rotate the node in the upper position, the physicsbody becomes green and moves up to the nodes position. After I translate the node down to the original position, the physicsbody stays in the upper position. Why is this behaviour? Is this because the type is .static?

I know if I set the physicsbody type to .kinematic (shown red in debug) mode it works as expected. The physicsbody adapts the translations and rotations. But with .static type I can place more objects before the fps drops than with .dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation for `SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbodytype/scnphysicsbodytypestatic) we learn that it is

> A physics body that is unaffected by forces or collisions and cannot move

However you can use [`resetTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514782-resettransform) to explicitly tell the engine that the node has moved and that the physics body needs to be updated:

> If you change the position or orientation of a node with an attached
>   static or dynamic physics body, call this method afterward to ensure
>   that the physics simulation incorporates the change. You need not call
>   this method for kinematic bodies.
>
> Note that dynamic and physics bodies
>   are designed to be moved only by the physics simulation or not at all.
>   You may use this method to move them regardless of this restriction,
>   but at a cost to performance.

Comment: FYI... call resetTransform on the node's physics body, like this: `node.physicsBody?.resetTransform()`